# Image in ImageView auto scale when display the same BitmapDrawable with another ImageView?

Tags: android, imageview

This situation I have met in Android and still can't find any solution.
I have an `ImageView` display by these code:

```
BitmapDrawable value = ...;
imageView1.setImageDrawable(value);
```

Then I use `imageView2` to display the same image in `Drawable`:

```
imageView2.setImageDrawable(value);
```

And ops,... the image in `imageView1` auto scale and become bigger than the older. (`imageView2` is bigger than `imageView1`).

Is there anyone saw this situation before?

Comment: please post your layout!

Comment: if you want the answer , its better to post layout and the code

Comment: sorry guys, I can't do this, cause the code is really complicated and flexible in our project. I just wanna ask to know that any one saw this before... I wanna post the code, but really I can't :))

Comment: Can I see your Layout file? Are you sure you are not having different params set on either of imageview?

Comment: Isn't it normal if you set an image to an imageView then that image would automatically fit the dimension of the imageView??? Since your imageView2 is bigger than imageView then it really should automatically scale.

Comment: you are asking for help and you are not sharing all the info required to answer...

Comment: @Thiagolr: Sorry bro, I know how ya feel about this :( but I just can't :( anyway, I think that I found the answer bellow :P thanks man

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Drawables are immutable, so the one bitmap is getting scaled and then shown by both ImageViews.
To get a different (unshared) version for the second one, try:

imageView2.setImageDrawable(value.mutate());